# Concurrent access to state which indicates count of available web service tokens

Tags: java, web-services, concurrency

I'm writing a library for managing access to service providers, whether they be a web service, a file system resource... In some circumstances the provider will require that a certain number of credits are purchased up front e.g. purchase 100 credits for an SMS messaging service.

I intend to store a count of the remaining credit against each service provider as shared state which I will synchronise however I'm concerned as to the amount of time I'll have to hang on to the lock i.e. in order to ensure that the count is only updated when the request has been made I'll have to synchronise acccess as such:

```
// Concrete class provides implementation
public abstract Result provide();

public Result provideIfInCredit() {
  Result result = null;
  synchronized(this) {
    if(remainingCredits > 0) {
      result = provide();
      remainingCredits--;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Is there a strategy I'm overlooking which would allow concurrent requests to a service provider where the call to provide() is not part of the lock?

Comment: Semaphore comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks @assylias however I'm unsure of how to apply a semaphore to my use case... I understand that a semaphore can nbe thought of as representing the number of available resources where a request for a semaphore decreases the number and a release of a semaphore increases the number of available resources. In my example the resource i.e. the number of credits will only ever go down. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JLove Let procedure which buys credits call Semaphore.release(NumOfCredits), and provideIfInCredit do Semaphore.tryAcquire(). If call simple aquire(), it would wait until next buying happens.